# Is db_query() limited to MySQL?

Tags: 7, database

I know db_select and Drupal's Database Abstraction Layer work across database implementations as long as there is a driver (mysql, postgresql and sqlite drivers included in core). But what about db_query? Should I patch contributed modules to make sure they work with sqlite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any function that is part of the database abstraction layer in Drupal 7 works with every database engine for which there are the necessary classes to work with that database engine.

If you look at the code of [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7), you will notice it is generic enough to work with every database engine.

```
function db_query($query, array $args = array(), array $options = array()) {
  if (empty($options['target'])) {
    $options['target'] = 'default';
  }

  return Database::getConnection($options['target'])->query($query, $args, $options);
}
```

This code is not different from the code executed by [db_select()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7).

```
function db_select($table, $alias = NULL, array $options = array()) {
  if (empty($options['target'])) {
    $options['target'] = 'default';
  }
  return Database::getConnection($options['target'])->select($table, $alias, $options);
}
```

If you compare those functions with the code executed from db_delete(), you will notice the functions are essentially wrappers around `Database::getConnection()`.

```
function db_delete($table, array $options = array()) {
  if (empty($options['target']) || $options['target'] == 'slave') {
    $options['target'] = 'default';
  }
  return Database::getConnection($options['target'])->delete($table, $options);
}
```

It is `Database::getConnection()` that, indirectly, builds the object necessary to execute the queries in the database engine, using the following code.

```
  $driver_class = 'DatabaseConnection_' . $driver;
  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/database/' . $driver . '/database.inc';
  $new_connection = new $driver_class(self::$databaseInfo[$key][$target]);
  $new_connection->setTarget($target);
  $new_connection->setKey($key);
```

As SQLite is supported in Drupal 7, `db_query()` doesn't need to be altered to execute optimized code for SQLite, as the code that it is optimized for that database engine is already contained in the [DatabaseConnection_sqlite](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!sqlite!database.inc/class/DatabaseConnection_sqlite/7).

Answer (score 0):

db_query works for all databases, see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7